# Build large(ish) unordered set with all data available at the beginning

Tags: c++, std, unordered-set

I have a situation where I need to optimize the creation of an unordered set. Expected number of elements is around 5-25M. My first thought is that I should prepare all data beforehand and do something like

```
unordered_set s(data);
```

instead of

```
for (auto& elem : data)
    s.insert(elem);
```

Can the STL unordered set use bulk loading methods and speed up its creation? How can I tweak the parameters of the hash table (bucket size etc) if I know prior to the table construction the expected number of elements?

Comment: Out of interest, have you already tried profiling these two variants?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've timed the second one and it seemed really slow (0.5 secs for 6M elements). My focus now is on whether I can use functions like `rehash` to notify the table for the upcoming size

Comment: What type of elements? Integers, strings (how long)?

Comment: @user2079 Pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My focus now is on whether I can use functions like rehash to notify the table for the upcoming size

Suppose you call

```
unordered_set s(begin(data), end(data));
```

while the standard doesn't dictate an implementation, a good implementation will be able to discern the number of elements, and preallocate the size accordingly. If you look at the source code used by gcc (by me `/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/hashtable.h`), for example, it uses

```
 _M_bucket_count = std::max(_M_rehash_policy._M_next_bkt(__bucket_hint),
                _M_rehash_policy.
                _M_bkt_for_elements(__detail::
                            __distance_fw(__f,
                                  __l)));
 _M_buckets = _M_allocate_buckets(_M_bucket_count);
```

so it already preallocates size based on the number of elements.

The problem might be different, though. If you look at [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set), it states:

> constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last). Sets max_load_factor() to 1.0.

This saves space, but might cause collisions. To reduce the collisions, you could use

```
unordered_set s(begin(data), end(data), k * data.size());
```

where *k > 1* is some constant. This corresponds to a load factor that is *1 / k*. YMMV.

Comment: If input iterator does not comply to RandomAccessIterator requirements, then the 'good' implementation will spend O(n) time trying to calculate the size of the input range. That's why I hardly doubt any common impementation is 'good' in this regard.

Comment: @iehrlich Iterator traits are typically used to determine that, however.

Comment: @iehrlich FWIW, g++ preallocates based on the sequence length, for example (see update).

Comment: @iehrlich Thanks for your apt comment. It was a good point to raise.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite broad and interesting.

First of all, there is a special method called [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve) - it allows you to pre-allocate the storage for a number of elements before actually inserting them. Pre-allocating sufficient memory (and avoiding re-locations during the instertion) is a very powerful approach, which is commonly used for large data sets. Note, that it is also available for various standard containers, including `vector`, `unordered_map` etc.

Secondly, if you're using C++11, you might benefit from using move-semantics while inserting the elements into your container (of course, given you don't need them in your feed once they are placed in the set, which should be true for 5 to 25 millions of objects).

These two techniques are a good start. You may need to tune it further by setting different hashing function, or even  choosing different implementation of an unordered_set. But at this point, you should provide more information: what are your value objects and what is their life-cycle; what insertion time do you find acceptable in your application.

**EDIT:** of course it's all about C++11, as unordered_set was not available prior to it. Shame on me :)